# Creating reusable component in Angularjs 1.5.x which can access parent controller fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I am trying to create a reusable component which can be reused accross the application. We are using Angular 1.5.8

There is some data that needs to be passed from the parent component to child component. (Typically an object holding information). It can be

After some reading i found out there is attribute called require where you can mention the name of the parent component and then can access the methods of parent controller.

The main drawback is the parent component name is hardcoded.  And that limits the reusability of the component.

Is there anyway where we can pass data from parent component to child in dynamic way.

Code sample

```
app.component('parent',
{ restrict: 'E', 
  scope: {}, 
  templateUrl: 'app/parent.html', 
  controller: function(){
    var vm = this;
     vm.sayHello = function (){
           return {
                  parentName : 'parent1',
                  parentCode : 'parentCode1'
             };
       };
   }, 
  controllerAs: 'vm'}); 

 app.component('child', {
   require: {
parentCtrl: '^^parent'
  },
controller: function() {
var self = this;
this.$onInit = function() {
  self.parentCtrl.sayHello();
};
}
 });
```

Thanks

Comment: what you  tried ... show us the code

Comment: depends what do you want to reuse ? do you want to reuse function data or service ?? please be clear

Comment: Hi Ameya the idea is the parent controller will have function that the child component will call in order to get the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add bindings to child component in the definition object:

```js
app.component('child',{ 
  bindings:{
    data: '<'
  }, 
  templateUrl: 'app/child.html', 
  controller: childController});
```

then in parent.html you use the following:

Plunkr here : https://plnkr.co/edit/d6wS1dHVsYT3fNkMUVNY?p=preview

angular.noop is just an empty function so you can put if you do not have any controller for the component
$ctrl is default if you do not specify controllerAs alias name

Also you can use on child component $onInit() $onChanges() and $onDestroy() lifecycle hooks to control what the component will do at certain points.

If you use .component drop the restrict: 'E' is already an element

Comment: Will add a js fiddle in a moment

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Works like charm.. People like you make stackoverflow.com an awesome place..